# How to check which element caused an on change event to fire

Tags: javascript, jquery

Js novice here.  I've got a few unfinished pages I've inherited, on one page there are two drop downs which use an on change jquery event to create child dropdowns once a value is selected in the first one.

After speaking with the user it is not desired for one of these drop downs to do that.  The two sets of drop downs have different names and IDs but the same classes.  I'd like to catch the name or ID of which drop down was modified in the event but so far have had no luck syntactically doing that.

EDIT: I've added the on change event code here for reference.  The html dropdowns are generated by some really wonky nested partial views

```
   $(document).on("change",
   ".genericClass",
   function () {

      $(this).addClass("updated");
      if ($(this).hasClass("blank")) {
         $(this).removeClass("blank");
         var $newAddRow = $(this).parents(".relationControl:first").find(".relationAddRowTemplate")
             .clone().removeClass("relationAddRowTemplate")
             .addClass("relationAddRow")
             .show();
         $newAddRow.insertAfter($(this));
      }
   });
```

Comment: You can use the [`event.target`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_target.asp) property, but without any code it's hard to help you further than that

Comment: The event object that is used as the first parameter of the event handler, will have a target property. So if you have a select handler: `select.addEventListener( 'change', event => {});` then `event.target` will give you the select that was changed.

Comment: Please show use the HTML and JS for both dropdowns. See these docs on how to create a [Minimal, Verifiable and Complete Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to make a good question

Comment: [relatedTarget](https://api.jquery.com/event.relatedTarget/): The other DOM element involved in the event, if any

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code, you will the get the id of select element caused event triggered

```
 $(document).on("change",
    ".genericClass",
    function () {
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
        $(this).addClass("updated");
        if ($(this).hasClass("blank")) {
            $(this).removeClass("blank");
            var $newAddRow = $(this).parents(".relationControl:first").find(".relationAddRowTemplate")
                .clone().removeClass("relationAddRowTemplate")
                .addClass("relationAddRow")
                .show();
            $newAddRow.insertAfter($(this));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you have two options:

1- Use listener

`select.addEventListener( 'change', event => {}); then event.target`

2- add scope watch

```
$scope.$watch(function () { return self.selectedValue; }, function (newValue, oldValue) {
                    if (newFilter != oldFilter) {
                     // call what ever you want   
                    }
                }, true);
```